# Is Feudal Elective better than Confederate Partition?

Tags: crusader-kings-3

I'm 60 years old, it's year 988, and I hold 3+1 Kingdoms.

The succession law is Confederate Partition, and there's no way I can enhance it to a better Partition (so destroying titles would be useless).

Can switching all of the secondary kingdoms to Feudal Elective help me? That is, how can I understand if I have a chance of winning them, rather than them going to random Dukes not even related to me?

*PS: this is an Ironman game, please consider this when writing your answer.*

Comment: (after about 1 year I reread this, and I'm puzzled by what I meant with "3+1" kingdoms. Maybe one was titular only?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you've got a good heir **and/or** good relations with your vassals **and/or** lots of hooks to use I think going elective could be worth it.

Elective can be high risk/high reward, if you got good relations with your vassals they're more likely to vote for your candidate though it's far from a sure thing, if your candidate is pretty craptastic as can be the case with the eldest they might not vote for them regardless of how much <strike>bribes</strike> *affection* you send their way. You can however use a weak hook to force them to vote for your candidate for 10 years, you only need to <strike>blackmail</strike> *convince* a majority of the votes.

If you got none of these things Confederate might be a  better bet, getting titles from your siblings is a pain but much less so then getting them from random strangers.

Answer (score 5):

Using Elective succession could potentially help you.

If a title has an election, you can see a list of all candidates and electors, and who has pledged their votes to whom. In your case, if you have good relations with the electors for the secondary Kingdom titles, you could end up keeping a title you stand to lose. If you know that you will lose the titles under confederate, it might be worth it to switch.

[image: Screenshot of election]

Comment: +1 There is one downside though: with Partition I lose them but at least they are my siblings. With Elective they may end up being complete strangers…

Comment: @o0'. That's true, but your siblings are not your friends. Children get claims on all titles held by their father. So your brother with a kingdom can be a much greater threat than a stranger with a kingdom. Also, I *think* your heir should get a claim on all the kingdoms held by his father which don't go to people who are now his vassals, regardless of whether they lost them through partition or through elections.So you can take those titles back through bigger army diplomacy in either case.

Answer (score 5):

If you are a Dynasty Head, you can "Disinherit" your least favorite sons.

Yes, it takes some Renown to do so, but it can be worth it.

The best way to deal with this succession problem is having a single Empire title. In that case, the lost Kingdoms will become vassals because you still own a higher title. There still might be time before you die to work towards that title!

Comment: +1 Good point regarding the Empire – I was kind of enjoying being a vassal for a change, but yeah.